# 7405 1.1 Magento 1.9.1.0

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade

I don't have SSH access and cannot find where to download a FTP version of 7405 1.1, currently magentary.com does not contain the 1.1 patch. Does anyone have an idea how to get it or if it is possible to patch a .sh file with no SSH access.

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the patch from magento.com. You will need to create an account if you do not have one then just go to https://www.magentocommerce.com/download and find the patch you need under "Release Archive".

If you only have ftp access then you will need to apply the patch locally and upload the changes with ftp. Far from an ideal solution but it could be your only option.

Comment: Thankyou, good idea.

Comment: Its probably worth noting it really isn't a good idea to use FTP to deploy changes. You could probably get away with it for apps with smaller code bases but Magento being pretty large it could take a long time to deploy. Also then there is no easy to roll back changes either. But as I said, if you only have FTP access it could be your only option.

Comment: Everytime I use FTP I do a backup to all the files I am changing/have changed. I'm being pretty cautios. I'm looking at quotes now for VPS/Co-Lo servers as our shop is getting pretty large

Comment: Just a side note not sure if you would know. But after applying patches my slideshow is not showing? I added it into the backend Permissions > blocks but it is still not showing even after clearing cache?

Comment: That does sound like the block permissions but that was from supee 6788, have you applied that patch too? Make your you have the correct block identifier. Other than that, not sure sorry, really depends how its built.

Comment: I have definitely applied that patch to (did both of them today) the Slideshow is called "Dolpin_Slideshow" which I have added along with just "slideshow" but nothing is still coming up. Is there a way to check in the error log if that Block is being called and then blocked so I can see what name it is using?

Comment: I might just ask a new question regarding that issue, thankyou for your help.

Comment: it should be in {extension_namespace}/{block} format so it should at least have a slash in it. again, not sure about that exact extension but will be something like "dolphin_slideshow/slideshow" or "slideshow/slideshow"

Comment: Thankyou I'll try that

Comment: It worked, you are a whisker away from a super hero! Thanks a million dude.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
print("<PRE>");
passthru("/bin/bash PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1.sh");
print("</PRE>");
?>
```

Now Save it to filename.php. Then upload the file to your root folder then run it from url http://www.domain.com/filename.php

Hope it will help.